# How to "clear" IPs allocation?

Tags: vpn, openvpn

my server is allocating 4 IPs per new key generated. I read in documentation that this is a normal behavior when using a /30 subnet (I'm not sure if I'm using this  :roll: )
Anyway, I noted that I always get the same ip address (10.10.1.6) when I connect to my server. If I change key, I always get another IP address, looks like they are static for each Key/CommonName.
Here's my server.ovpn:

```
local MYIPADDRESS
mode server
port 1194
dev tun
dev-node VPN
server 10.10.1.0 255.255.255.0
push "redirect-gateway def1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
comp-lzo
tls-server
tls-auth keys/shared.key 0
ca keys/ca.crt
cert keys/server.crt
key keys/server.key
dh keys/dh4096.pem
keepalive 10 60
max-clients 50
cipher AES-256-CBC
script-security 2
tls-verify "C:\\Manager\\RevokerMgr.exe"
log-append keys/logs.txt
```

**First question is:** Should I add topology subnet to my server config? Assuming that I'm beginner in routing and network concepts in general. But this way looks like I'll get 1 IP per Key/CommonName, what looks simpler.

**Second question is:** How I "clear" the entries created? For example, if a client was occupying the IP 10.10.1.6, and this client is inactive now, how can I free this IP for another clients?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How I "clear" the entries created?

OpenVPN Stores this in the persist file.  You can set this file by using the `ifconfig-pool-persist` option.  If you don't set it then many distros will automatically add one at some logical location under var.  Anyway, find your persist file, or manually specify one in your configuration.  Once you know where it is, just remove the line for the particular host/cert.  It is a simple text file.  I believe you will need to restart the OpenVPN daemon for this to be read.

> Should I add topology subnet to my server config? Assuming that I'm beginner in routing and network concepts in general. But this way looks like I'll get 1 IP per Key/CommonName, what looks simpler.

There really isn't much value in doing this, plus the /30 topology is used for compatibility with some buggy clients.  There is more then enough RFC1918 address space to just let OpenVPN grab 4 addresses per connection.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll accept your answer. But only one thing before: there's no default value when ifconfig-pool-persist file is not specified? I mean, where is the file with the current IPs when it's not specified?

Comment: See it gets tricky.  Some Linux distributions add a default in the OpenVPN startup script, some don't.  You could run a command like `lsof -p {pid} -n` where {pid} is the process ID of your OpenVPN server.  You should see the files it has open which will include the ifconfig persist database if it is using one.  I suppose looking at your config again you are running on Windows?  If that is the case, I am not sure what your defaults will look like.

Comment: Yes I'm into Windows... Anyway, thank you, I'll be using the ifconfig-pool-persist to get this done. Thank's!!